# Gutenberg - What is the best way to save/update post meta?

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, block-editor

What would be the best way in Gutenberg to save/update post meta (not from a block). I can't find an API for it.

I was thinking of doing some ajax in `componentDidMount` using `wp.ajax.post`

Any advice would be much appreciated.